# Conditionally Change a List Item Attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a super beginner with javascript so forgive me if this is pretty basic, but I've several hours searching for a solution and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I'd like to hide a single list item identified by the id="change" items if a particular condition is met. However, it doesn't seem like the javascript code below is doing anything as the "Hide Me" list item continues to appear.

```
<script>
      var x = 1;
      if(x == 1) {
      document.getElementById("change").style.display = "none";
      }
</script>


<style>
    .default{display: block;}
</style>

<ul>
    <li class="default">Show Me</li>
    <li id="change" class="default">Hide Me</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When writing your code in the StackSnippet, your code works as expected; 'Hide Me' gets hidden, and 'Show Me' remains visible. Perhaps you have failed to reference your JavaScript file correctly? Or have you written your JavaScript **inside** of your HTML file, as is shown above? Because in that case, the element won't have been created by the time you're trying to target it ;)

Comment: your code (as shown!) does not work because the script block is running before that element is in the DOM, therefore `document.getElementById("change")` is `null` - check the browser **developer** tools console, you'll see an error pointing to that line, something about null not having the property style ... try moving the `<script>` block after the `<ul>...</ul>`  block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to debug your code is to try and see where the error begins. Right now, try to run the following code:

```
alert(document.getElementById("change"));
```

By doing that, you will see that it outputs "null" meaning that it couldn't find anything with the id "change."

This occurs because the script is at the very beginning, before any of your html, and specifically before the item with the "change" id. You want to move the entire script part to the very end like this:

```
<style>
    .default{display: block;}
</style>

<ul>
    <li class="default">Show Me</li>
    <li id="change" class="default">Hide Me</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var x = 1;
    if(x == 1) {
         document.getElementById("change").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script>` to the bottom and it should work. Reason being, you are trying to manipulate a DOM element that has not yet been rendered.

It is standard practice to include all scripts/script files at the bottom of the page `<body>` to prevent this issue:

```
<body>
    <style>
        .default{display: block;}
    </style>

    <ul>
        <li class="default">Show Me</li>
        <li id="change" class="default">Hide Me</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        var x = 1;
        if(x == 1) {
            document.getElementById("change").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```